# WordPress Custom User Creation Script

Tags: php, wordpress

What do I have to include to be able to use `wp_create_user`?

My current includes are

`include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-config.php");
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-includes/registration.php");
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-includes/user.php");`

But it never creates the user.

What am I missing?

Here is the full code block.

```
global $wpdb;

    $user_name = $_GET['user_login'];
    $user_password = $_GET['user_password'];
    $user_email = $_GET['user_email'];

    /* echo $user_name . " " . $user_password . " " . $user_email . " <br />"; */

$user_id = username_exists( $user_name );

if ( !$user_id ) { // User doesn't exist. Create user. Notify via JSON

    $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_name, $user_password, $user_email );

    echo '{"success": "'. $user_id .'"}';

} else { // User exists. Return JSON error.

    $msg = 'User already exists.';
    echo '{"error": "'. $msg .'"}';
}
```

Comment: Do you end up with a success output?

Comment: I must not, because the `wp_users` table doesn't update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Include path problem occurred during migration.

Answer (score 0):

The `wpdb` class is in `wp-includes/wp-db.php`. You can probably just use it like this (note, I haven't tested this)

```
require_once('wp-includes/wp-db.php');
$wpdb = new wpdb();
//Do your add user stuff
```

Comment: Including `wp-db.php` had no effect.

Comment: Do you get any output at all?

Comment: Problem was solved. Actually including `wp-db.php` created more problems once I fixed the include path issues.